# In Symfony2, what folder do I save a multi entity class in?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, entities

I am new to Symfony2 and I am not sure where I should save a class that updated multiple tables(entities).

From reading documentation and tutorials it says I should not put any other tables reference within the entity class; I could put it within the controller class, but again many people have said this class should be as simple as possible and not include business logic; Not in repositories, because these are used for query data and not for update or inserting.

Is there a standard folder structure where another type of class for working with multiple entities(tables) should be saved? Should the business logic really be stored in the controller classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony2 is very flexible in this regard.

You're right, entities are for one "table" only.

I would suggest you look into [Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html), as they are a good way to move your code from a controller to a separate class. You basically call your service and use the functions it provides. This will slim your controller down.

Comment: Services huh? I have thought services could be used for this but was not sure. I have used services for things like twig extensions. I think these are the best option. I will create a service for adding product to an invoice, which will update the invoice amount, add the product to the list and add history to a history table.

Comment: Yes, atleast this is my interpretation. I haven't found a definitive example of how a project should be structured, with examples. I find studying bundles on Github very helpful tho, especially those from FriendsOfSymfony (FOS) as they are very true to the Symfony standards.